# Adding Ordered Sequence Numbers to Child Records

Tags: trigger, sequential

I am trying to write a simple trigger that adds a sequence number to a list of child activities based on the date the activity is scheduled for. Basically I want to get all Activity__c records for each parent object Parent__c, based on their Scheduled_Date__c fields I will add a sequence number to the field Activity_Sequence__c (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.)

THIS HAS BEEN FIXED, SEE BELOW FOR NOW WORKING CODE

```
trigger ActivitySequence on Activity__c (after insert, after update) {
//create a list of activities to update
List<Activity__c> activitiesToUpdate = new List<Activity__c>();
//Parent Ids
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
//List of Parents
List<Parent__c> parentListById = new List<Parent__c>();

if(!activitySequence.hasAlreadyCreatedSequence())
{ 

  for(Activity__c vo: Trigger.New)
  {
    //add all parent object ids that have activities into the Set
    parentIds.add(vo.Parent__c);
  }

    if(parentIds.size() > 0)
    {    
      //create a list of Parents and children
      parentListById = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Activity_Sequence__c, Scheduled_Date__c FROM Activities__r ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c) FROM Parent__c WHERE Id IN :parentIds];                             
    }

    if(parentListById.size() >0)
    {
        //get each parent in the list
        for(Parent__c cs: parentListById)
        {
          integer idx = 0;

          //get the child activities for each parent in the list
          for(Activity__c ac: cs.Activities__r)


             {
                ac.Activity_Sequence__c = '(' + idx + ')';
                activitiesToUpdate.add(ac);
                idx = idx+1;       
              }
            }
        activitySequence.setAlreadyCreatedSequence();

        update activitiesToUpdate;
    }

    }

}
```

And here's my class to prevent recursive trigger

```
 //public class to stop recursive trigger

public class activitySequence {

    private static boolean alreadySequencedActivities = false;

    public static boolean hasAlreadyCreatedSequence() {
        return alreadySequencedActivities;
    }

    public static void setAlreadyCreatedSequence() {
        alreadySequencedActivities = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicate id in list because of the following:

```
for(EXObject__c w: exList) {
   while(i<=listSize){
     w.Activity_Sequence__c = '(' + i + ' of ' + listSize + ')';
     newList.add(w); // !! if listsize > 1, then w's id is same!
     i++;
   }
}

update newList;
```

You have two loops, the first `for loop` goes through all retrieved ExObject__c and the inner while loop goes through them again!  Thus if you retrieve more than one ExObject__c, you will add the same object to newList more than once and hence the duplicate ids

1. Use IN, not `=` in the SOQL when using collection bind variables
2. After you update newList, your trigger will be called again (and probably again and again). Resolve this by looking at [Preventing Recursive Triggers recipe](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers)

The above won't *per se* solve your business application problem but, in conjunction with diligent use of system.debug statements, you should be able to diagnose your code.

Comment: thank you @crop1645 . I found the tutorial very helpful in my understanding of recursive triggers.